# React js core UI build error on compilation

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, core-ui

Am recently switched my domain [enter image description here][1]to React Js and trying to learn . I have been trying to create an admin panel using Core UI Reactjs components. But it shows an error like "*This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed* " on the compilation.[][1]

Comment: we need a fully reproducible example.  otherwise how can we ever figure out what the problem is?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below commands:

> npm cache clean --force 
> npm cache verify

Then delete the **node_modules**, and run the below code

> npm install --force